# Error with greek (first letter) filenames in Ubuntu

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am working on Ubuntu server 16.04 with PHP 5.6, Apache2.4 and Mysql. I have a joomla site (3.8) in Greek language and I have a weird problem with the downloaded files. Although all of configurations for charset are "utf-8" (apache, php, server locale, joomla language), when I try to download a file with greek filename, because of apache(?) "cuts" the first letter from the file. For example, the uploaded filename is "Κ1234_ΒΓΔ" and the downloaded filename is "1234_ΒΓΔ". Any ideas for this problem/error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your encoding is wrong then, look at using ISO 8859-7 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) for Latin/Greek alphabets

Comment: Apache's encoding is wrong? For Greek alphabets, I use "windows-1253"

Comment: In apache2.conf, I changed "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" to "AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-7", I restarted it but the same problem.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution... The problem was in the custom php code for downloading files and specifically the problem was in "pathinfo()" function. This function doesn't work correctly when you parse utf-8 path/filenames and the solution is to insert, before usage pathinfo():
`setlocale(LC_ALL,'*your_lang*.UTF-8'); 
like setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

Filename is sent to client through HTTP headers. Headers may contains encoding informations so, you cannot be sure that the browser will encode it BEFORE the end of headers.

With this test code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=testΔ.txt");
echo 1;
?>
```

During my test firefox (correctly) encoded the filename using UTF8, but internet explore used iso8859-1.

Comment: I can download the testΔ.txt...... The files I download are pdf, and in php code i have header ("Content-Type: application/pdf"). I don't think that the problem is here but i can't understand where is the problem?!?!

Comment: If you could download the right filename the problem is not in php/apache, maybe in joomla. Do you have custome code for download?

Comment: Yes, I have custom code php for downloading pdf... The same code uses for downloading pdf and other files in other site and works perfect on windows server.